# cannot initialize cocoa pods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to install cocoa pods into my project, but and getting `No Xcode project found, please specify one` when I run `pod init`
In my project folder there is no xcode project, only an project.xcworkspace, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you did `pod init` inside the project folder? Also are you sure cocoapods are correctly setup on your machine?

Comment: "successfully installed cocoa pods" after a ```sudo gem install cocoapods``` I'm also in the right folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` (change the path, of course, if your Xcode is in a different location). That command should set the default path to the developer tools that `pod` is probably looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You must be too far out or far into the project folder. Try to cd out or in and try to init the pod again.